# Notice: Array to string conversion in PHP Json problems

Tags: php, json

I'm very new to php I have been watching some youtube videos

I have a json file

```
[{"name":"hally","ip":{"ip":[1,2,3,4]}},{"name":"Olojak","ip":{"ip":[11,22,33,44]}},{"name":"Andy","ip":{"ip":[111,222,333,444]}},{"name":"NoMad","ip":{"ip":[1111,2222,3333,4444]}},{"name":"ni","ip":{"ip":[11111,22222,33333,44444]}},{"name":"Nish","ip":{"ip":[111111,222222,333333,444444]}},{"name":"hs","ip":{"ip":[1111111,2222222,333333,4444444]}},{"name":"Kif","ip":{"ip":[11111111,22222222,33333333,44444444]}},{"name":"Kip","ip":{"ip":[111111111,111111111,111111111,11111111]}}]
```

and i want to display each name and ip address

this is my php file

```
<?php 
$jsondata = file_get_contents("info.json");
$names = json_decode($jsondata, true);

foreach ($names as $user){
    echo $user['name']."<br/>";

    echo "IP:".$user['ip'];
    echo "<br/>";
};

//echo "<br/>"; 
    
echo "<pre>";
print_r($names);
echo "</pre>";



?>
```

but im getting the error

> Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\test.php on
> line 13

and im not sure why any help would be appricated

Comment: Each IP has 4 elements. They are arrays, not strings.

Comment: ok so could you explain to me where im going wrong and what needs to be done ? Im trying my best to understand

Comment: Something like `echo "IP:" . implode(".", $user['ip']);`

Comment: thanks for that, i tryed it just now and got the "Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\test.php on line 13" error

Comment: see: https://3v4l.org/K21gm

Comment: For some reason, the `ip` key has another array with an `ip` key, so `implode('.', $user['ip']['ip'])`.